# how to retrieve session value in plugin in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, session, cakephp, plugins

I integrated "blueimp" image uploader in CakePHP 3, I put "imagehandler" in plugin folder who is responsible for uploading and all other actions. it is working perfectly but I need to access user_id from Session in "imageHandler" (plugin file)  but I could not get it.  I did  it like this

```
include('../plugins/UploadHandler.php');  
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
```

It works but I learned from SO that I need to pass $this argument if i need to access session in plugin file like this.

```
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($this);
```

In initiliaze function of this file, I tried to read it. but other code use $this give error.

But code in "UploadHandler" file gives the error.
**can you suggest any idea how I can access session value in plugin file.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make yourself comfortable with [**the asking guide**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add more information to your question that helps making your problem reproducable.

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error message**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP! Also show/describe the proper context, ie show/highlight the code that actually triggers the error, and please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version - thanks!